# HitTest Multiple MovieClips with Array

Tags: actionscript-3, hittest

I have a `MovieClip` exported to ActionScript called `smallGainPoints`. What i want to do is create multiple instances of this `MovieClip` on the stage in a linear or diagonal path. When this is accomplished i want a `hitTestObject` to take place between the Points array and the Player. The points are added to stage where i would want them to be, but the HitTest wont initiate.

Here is how i set up the Functions:

This Function is added in my Gameloop which is called from an onEnterFrame handler:

```
private function checkPlayerHitPoints():void 
{
    for (var j:int = 0; j < aPointsArray.length; j++)
    {
        //get current points in j loop
        var currentPoints:smallGainPoints = aPointsArray[j];

        //test if player is hitting current point
        if (player.hitTestObject(currentPoints))
        {
            //remove point on stage
            currentPoints.destroyPoints()
            //remove point from array
            aPointsArray.splice(j, 1);

            nScore += 5;
            updateHighScore();
        }
    }
}
```

Im not sure if i did this right but i want to add multiple instances of the points in a line so the player can gather as much points as possible. So i created a function and set the positions then added the function in my constructor as so `addPointsToStage()` so it doesn't loop every frame.

```
private function addPointsToStage():void
{
    for (var i = 0; i < nPoints; i++)
    {
        points = new smallGainPoints();
        stage.addChild(points);
        points.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2);
        points.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2);

        points = new smallGainPoints();
        stage.addChild(points);
        points.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) + 200;
        points.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2);
    }
```

This is how I initiated the array:

```
public var points:smallGainPoints;
    private var nPoints:Number = 5;
    private var aPointsArray:Array;
```

Then in my Constructor i added:

```
aPointsArray = new Array();
```

So the points are added to the stage but the hittest doesnt work. Please help!

Comment: First put a trace just before your hitTest line. Trace out the positions of the `player` and the `currentPoints`. Then see if you are getting the values you would expect. Also try putting a trace inside the hitTest if statement. You might find it is actually getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `addPointsToStage` method, you never add your `smallGainPoints` object to the array.

After this line:

```
points = new smallGainPoints();
```

Push the new points object onto the `aPointsArray` array:

```
aPointsArray.push(points);
```

**EDIT:**

A better way to add your points in a row might be like this:

```
private function addPointsToStage():void
{
    var startPoint:Point = new Point(stage.stageWidth / 2, stage.stageHeight / 2);
    var spacing:Number = 50;

    for (var i = 0; i < nPoints; i++)
    {
        points = new smallGainPoints();
        aPointsArray.push(points);
        addChild(points);
        points.x = startPoint.x + (spacing * i);
        points.y = startPoint.y;
    }
}
```

This `for loop` will add a bunch of `smallGainPoint` objects in a row, starting from the center of the screen and going right.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam. The .push seem to do the trick. I traced the points and all 2 are getting traced on stage it seems every frame so 25 frames/sec. The only bug i am having is that the player is only hittesting with one of the points not both.

Comment: No worries. You will need to push both your points onto the array. If you found an answer you think is correct, then remember to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah something weird is going on. When i trace(aPointsArray.length); in the addPointsToStage(); function inside the for loop i get 2,4  but when i remove the second  aPointsArray.push(points);  in the for loop and just leave one i get 1,2 which i think is correct right? I have to be doing something wrong because it traces my hittest when they collide but it only destroys 1 or sometimes it doesnt destroy any.

Comment: I am not too sure why you are adding two points in each loop. And you are adding all the points in the same positions.

Comment: Oh I think I was over thinking things. I added two pints because I thought that's how you had to do it in order to get then lined up on the stage. I want like 5 points in a line on stage and the player shoot a ball to try to get then all so I thought I needed to make their positions like that. And add new points but that's why I have the for loop haha.

Comment: So yeah thats a seperate problem i guess now i understand what i was doing wrong. Its just how to add all 5 of them to the stage at the same time.

Comment: @user2233653 Just edited my answer with a way you might want to do your loop to position your points objects.

Comment: wow that answer would have taken forever to figure out. It hitTest with 3 out of 5 of the points another bug haha. But ill try to figure it out. You've been more than helpful. You sir have some skill. I took a c++ programming class last year but kind of forgot about all the math involved cant go back and refresh since they stole my computer with all my programs and notes on it.

Comment: No worries. You should check out gotoandlearn.com for some beginner friendly AS3 video tutorials.